# Does C allow casting a struct type to itself?

Tags: c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, struct

So we have a struct type like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    U64 low;
    U64 high; 
} U128;
```

Then somewhere in the code as a result of macro expansion there is an assignment like this:

```
*ptr = (U128)value;
```

Where `ptr` is of `U128*`. And this causes the following error:

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'U128' to 'U128'
```

The question is: Are such self casts allowed in C? Am I just spotted a compiler bug?

Additional question:

This is a generalized macro that allows 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, etc. as arguments, and other types are typedefd as numbers and work without problems: are there any workaround? I would like to avoid memcpy for performance reasons.

Comment: In C, shouldn't you write `(struct U128)value`?

Comment: @Eregrith the struct is an anonymous struct `typedef`ed to `U128` so it's correct. I think the cast itself is incorrect, try this `*ptr = *((U128 *)&value);` does it work?

Comment: @iharob Ah yes I misread it.

Comment: Maybe you can take a pointer to the var, cast it to the appropriate pointer type, then dereference? Something like this: `*ptr = *((u111*)&value)`

Comment: not using memcpy() is unlikely to save any execution time, as the compiler, in the background, to copy a 16 byte entity (on less than a 64 bit architecture) will probably insert a 'hidden' call to memcpy().  Which would make the code more difficult to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The (draft C11) standard text that requires this behavior is in §6.5.4.2:

> Unless the type name specifies a void type, the type name shall specify atomic, qualified, or unqualified scalar type, and the operand shall have scalar type

In other words, you can't cast `struct`s *at all*.

One fix could of course be to remove the right-hand side cast, or do a bitwise copy:

```
memcpy(ptr, &value, sizeof *ptr);
```

This will perhaps be optimized away, since the size being copied is quite small. Note that `sizeof *ptr` is a safer choice, using `sizeof value` would risk overflowing if the incoming `value` has an unexpected type.